# find unAuthourize error in interceptor in angular8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i need to find error status in intercptor in anglar8 for send refresh token .

when the request is unAuthorized , server send me this error :

```
{
"IsSuccess": false,
"StatusCode": 6,
"Message": "{\"Exception\":\"No Access\",\"StackTrace\":\"   at Travel.Framework.DepencyInjection . . . "}"
}
```

i try for get error with this code in interceptor :

```
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    let refreshTokoenSending = false;
    let token = this.authService.getRowToken("accessToken");

    return next.handle(this.addTokenToRequest(req, token))
    .pipe(
        map(res => {
            console.log(res);
            throw Observable.throw('error')
        }),
        retry(1),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            let errorMessage = '';
            if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
                // client-side error
                console.log('client :',error.error.message)
            } else {
                // server-side error
                console.log('error :',error.status ,error.message)
            }
            console.log('out',errorMessage);
            return throwError(errorMessage);
        })
    )
}


private addTokenToRequest(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
    return request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } });
}
```

but it show me this in console :

> {type: 0}
>
> error : undefined
>
> rxjs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Observable.throw is not a function

**now how can i find status code for send refresh token in this interceptor ????**

server send me this response :

[image]

Comment: it says Observable.throw is not a function... you need to use throwError in your map as you are lower down in your catch error.

Comment: how can i solve partB of my question ?

Comment: servers should send a 401 or 403 status code when unauthenticated or unauthorized. fix your server to do that then check for the status code

Comment: @bryan60 i update the question and put the server reponse

Comment: yea i answered, the server isn't done right. fix it to return proper status codes

Comment: how can i get this response in interceptor ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204144/discussion-between-mr-programer-and-bryan60).